# Hiding first sheet in excel workbook with pivot tables generated using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I generated a workbook containing 6 sheets using Apache POI, 3 of them with pivot tables and the remaining 3 being the data source to these pivot tables.

```
Sheet 1 -> Data1
Sheet 2 -> PivotTable_Data1
Sheet 3 -> Data2
Sheet 4 -> PivotTable_Data2
Sheet 5 -> Data3
Sheet 6 -> PivotTable_Data3
```

Sheet names with "PivotTable" hold the pivot tables.

I have a requirement to hide the data sheets so that the generated workbook shows only the pivot table sheets, and the user may unhide the data sheets as he/she pleases.

I used the code below to hide the sheet.

`workbook.setSheetVisibility(workbook.getSheetIndex(sheet),SheetVisibility.HIDDEN);`

No matter how I try I am not able to hide Sheet 1 alone and this works well with Sheet 3 and 5.

I assume this might be due to the fact that the active sheet cannot be hidden. With this in mind, I tried setting sheet 2 as selected sheet/active tab, but this broke the pivot table.

I am aware of `SheetVisibility.VERY_HIDDEN` but I'm certain this will cause panic to the users, since it requires developer mode to be enabled to unhide the sheet.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For resolving such problems read the message of the error while rendering the pivot table in Excel. I suspect it is: "Cannot edit a Pivot Table in group edit mode ".
That means that some sheets are grouped (selected the same time). This is true if you are setting the second sheet to be the active sheet and do not unselect the first sheet. Then both sheets are selected.

So do:

```
workbook.getSheetAt(0).setSelected(false);
workbook.setActiveSheet(1);

...

workbook.setSheetVisibility(workbook.getSheetIndex(sheet),SheetVisibility.HIDDEN);
```

Background why rendering a pivot table fails in group edit mode:

If multiple sheets are grouped (selected the same time), then all changings in one of the grouped sheets goes to all selected sheets too. So the rendering of the pivot table, which changes cell contents, would also change cell contents in the other sheets which are also selected. This fails though.

Comment: Thank you sir. You were right about the error message, and I could see two sheets getting selected whenever this happens. setSelected was exactly the solution I was looking for. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. For a newbie, I think `selected` and `active` are the same (it's NOT), and my code caused exception: `Cannot edit a Pivot Table in group edit mode`, which confused me a lot, because in the Excel UI, it does show multiple worksheet are grouped.·. > This is true if you are setting the second sheet to be the active sheet and do not unselect the first sheet. Then both sheets are selected.